# Tikz Arrow Libraries: How can I migrate from arrows to arrows.meta without getting annoyed?

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have some legacy code that uses the `arrows` library, and I want to reuse some of that code in new work with the `arrows.meta` library (including, later, tweaking the arrow heads).

Rather than going through everything to fix `>=triangle 45` (etc), I thought I might just be able to define a new style to pass through to the new library. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
% Failed attempt at providing legacy arrowheads:
\tikzset{triangle 45/.tip={Triangle[angle=45]}}
\begin{document}
% Legacy tikzpicture:
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]
\draw[->] (0,0) -> (2,0);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, that fails miserably:

```
...
(d:/TeXlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.meta.code.tex
))
Runaway argument?
45 +0 +0 +0 \pgf@stop \expandafter \pgfarrowsaddtooptions \expandafter \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfarrowsfourparameters@.
<inserted text>
                \par
<*> test.tex
```

It looks like .tip is expecting more parameters, but I couldn't find anything in the manual to clarify this.

What am I doing, or expecting, wrong?

Comment: I think it should be something like `Triangle[angle=45:1pt 3]` (pag. 211)

Comment: @dcmst : That works, even though I don't really understand most of the parameters. If you'd care to post that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `angle` key should be specified in the form of `angle=<angle>:<dimension>`, where, according to the PGF manual:

> This key sets the **length** and the **width** of an arrow tip at the same time. The length  will be the cosine of `<angle>`, while the width will be twice the sine of half the `<angle>`.

So in the MWE given above, we'll have

```
Triangle[angle=45:3pt]
```

It is also possible to specify an optional argument:

```
Triangle[angle=45:1pt 5]
```

which according to the manual:

> if the optional factors are given, they add a certain multiple of the
>   line width to `<dimension>` before the sine and cosines are computed.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
% Failed attempt at providing legacy arrowheads:
\tikzset{triangle 45/.tip={Triangle[angle=45:3pt]}}
\begin{document}
% Legacy tikzpicture:
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=triangle 45]
\draw[->] (0,0) -> (2,0);  
\draw[-{Triangle[angle=45:1pt 5]}] (0,-.2) -> (2,-.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The key `angle'` does not require a `<dimension>` to be specified:

> Sets the width of the arrow to twice the tangent of `<angle>/2` times
>   the arrow length. This results in an arrow tip with an opening angle
>   of `<angle>` at its tip and with the specified length unchanged.

All the quotes are from the PGF manual, pag 188.