Understanding arrowtips in tikz
Edit: Solution has been discovered, and it has to do with changed keywords. You have to use a capital letter for the first letter of the old keyword in order to make it compatible with the functionality of arrows.meta in the tikzlibrary
Also, instead of using draw for coloring the borders, you can just list the color and use the fill=color to color the fill - Just make sure you make the arrowtip big enough so the difference of color in the fill can be seen visually
I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Given the instruction manual at https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows, it'd seem like you'd be able to customize everything regarding an arrowtip in tikz by writing {arrowtip[specifications]} while using arrows.meta from the tikzlibrary. I thought I'd followed the instructions precisely, but I got the following output when trying to execute some code:

Here's the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=1mm, -stealth] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[midway, above=5pt]{Standard stealth}; % Normal
    \draw[line width=1mm, -{stealth[scale=2]}] (3,0) -- (5,0) node[midway, above=5pt] {Scaled tip}; % Scale doesn't and other adjustments to the tip doesn't work
    \draw[line width=1mm, -{stealth[fill=red, draw=green]}] (6,0) -- (8,0) node[midway, above=5pt] {Colored tip}; % Getting an error using draw
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

As you can see, it seems like it's ignoring my adjustments to the tip. I even tried to scale the length and width separately and also tried to just adjust the length and width without scaling, but the commands just don't seem to work inside of the arrowtips for some odd reason, except for the fillcolor in the last example. Even then, I can't add a drawcolor, however, and I even get an error for trying that part.
Solutions as well as explanations of why my examples don't work are greatly appreciated. I want to understand arrowtips better so I don't encounter an issue like this in the future.

All about arrows.meta is described in tikz manual. From Your MWE follows, that you not use this library but just arrows which has not such functionality.

I've figured out the issue. It revolves in me not using a capital s on the stealth arrow. In order for it to be compatible with the functionality of arrows.meta, you have to capitalize the S since they've apparently redefined the syntax for this library (because they wanted to retain tthe functionality of the old one in-case someone is still interested in using it)

Hm, your understanding of problem seems to be wrong or  at least to simplified. tikz package has two libraries for arrows: arrows and arrows.meta (written by different authors) , which has different syntax due to different functionality which they offer. Consequently the names of arrows head should be different to clearly indicate which type of arrows head is in use.

I don't think so. It's been stated that the old arrows is considered deprecated now. Take a look: https://tikz.dev/library-arrows. There's also this thread which concludes that arrows.meta can do the same as arrows and more: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398819/why-should-we-use-arrows-meta-instead-of-arrows
Thus, I think it's relevant to highlight that us new users to LaTeX must update our methods to accomodate the new package, if we desire to take advantage of its increased functionality.

For better understanding consider my first comment and read the library documentation. If something in it is not clear to you, than please ask for help for clarifying this. Make a (so emphasized, a bit misleading) conclusion on some comments and one example is a bit exaggeration ...

I did. The reason I asked my question in the first place was because I couldn't find my answer in the manual (because I was clumsy enough to not pay attention to the capitalized letter, rookie mistake, I suppose) or in here, and I didn't encounter anywhere where it was explicitly mentioned that you must capitalize the first letter of the keywords for the old arrows in order for it to be compatible with the functionality of the new arrows.meta. This was what I needed help with, and people where kind enough to point that out:)

stealth is not an arrow tip in arrows.meta.
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1mm, -Stealth] (0,0) -- (2,0) node[midway, above=5pt]{Standard stealth};
\draw[line width=1mm, -{Stealth[scale=2]}] (3,0) -- (5,0) node[midway, above=5pt] {Scaled tip};
\draw[line width=1mm, -{Stealth[green, fill=red, scale=2]}] (6,0) -- (8,0) node[midway, above=5pt] {Colored tip};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Oh my gooooood, I figured out the issue from your example! The only difference is that you have a capital S in "stealth" and I don't. Do you coincidentally happen to know why that makes the difference?

@Atex TeX is case sensitive. As hpkristiansen said, the arrow tip stealth is not part of the arrows.meta library and is actually considered deprecated. The arrows.meta arrow tips are all capitalized. You can always do stealth/.tip=Stealth if you want to use the old name for the new tip.

Oooh, I didn't know this change in syntax. Is there any documentation for it? I don't believe I've encountered it anywhere. Seems like I must not only pay attention to the keywords of manuals, but also mind the capitalization (although I've noted that sometimes it doesn't matter whether you use capital letters or not)

Sorry. I was not very clear. There is no change in syntax- stealth and Stealth are two different tips. Always use Stealth from arrows.meta.
